# Exiting programmatically seems successful, but "Force stop" button is still active

Tags: android, exit

I'm trying to exit my application programmatically, so I call these lines:

```
my_activity.finishAndRemoveTask();
context.stopService(new Intent(context, mysvc.class));
```

The application seems closing:

```
com.my.package I/my_activity: onDestroy
I/mysvc: onDestroy
```

So both activity and service seems to be destroyed.

However, when I check in `Settings/Apps/App info`, my application seem to be still "force-stoppable" (i.e. Force stop button is still active).

When I press this "Force stop" button:

```
D/AppInfoDashboard: Stopping package com.my.package
I/ActivityManager: Force stopping com.my.package appid=xy, user=xy: from pid xy
I/ActivityManager: Killing xy:com.my.package/xy (adj xy): stop com.my.package
D/AppActionButtonControl: Sending broadcast to query restart status for com.my.package
D/AppActionButtonControl: Sending broadcast to query restart status for com.my.package
D/AppActionButtonControl: Got broadcast response: Restart status for com.my.package false
D/AppActionButtonControl: Got broadcast response: Restart status for com.my.package false
```

After pressing this button it gets inactive, and I believe my `com.my.package` application is successully (and fully) terminated.

So my question is, how can I reach this programmatically, if those lines of my code above doesn't make this? And also: why Android keeps my application in some quasi-running state if it explicitly asks for exit?

Please note, I don't want to kill my application on exit. I'd like to gracefully terminate it when user selects the "Exit" option from menu.

Comment: What you are currently doing would be gracefully terminating your app (stopping any services and finishing your activity). Android will keep your app in memory for some time so that it can start up faster if the user were to open it again.

Comment: Short answer: you can't kill your own app in Android, the OS is responsible for the lifecycle management of processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe my com.my.package application is successully (and fully) terminated.

A *lot* more has happened than that. The "Force Stop" button is not the sort of thing that you want users doing.

> how can I reach this programmatically, if those lines of my code above doesn't make this?

You cannot force-stop your own app.

> why Android keeps my application in some quasi-running state if it explicitly asks for exit?

Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/process-lifecycle):

> An unusual and fundamental feature of Android is that an application process's lifetime is not directly controlled by the application itself. Instead, it is determined by the system through a combination of the parts of the application that the system knows are running, how important these things are to the user, and how much overall memory is available in the system.

Having an "Exit" option in an Android app is very unusual. What you are presently doing isn't horrible as an implementation of "exit" logic, though users might get confused by having the app's task vanish.